# Intellij SonarLint 2.3 - ignore rule

Tags: intellij-idea, sonarlint, sonarlint-intellij

I've just updated SonarLint plugin for Intellij Idea to version 2.3.2.
Changelog says that since version 2.3 rule exclusion in connected mode should be available.

Below is my configuration, seems to be corrected, yet, ignored rule still pops up.

[image: Analysis configuration]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently, the exclusions must be defined in the SonarQube server. That's why it's only supported in the connected mode.

Sorry if change notes were not clear, I will update the title of https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLI-72.

Defining exclusions in the IDE will be supported at some point. Feel free to follow/vote the corresponding ticket: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLI-97

Comment: SLI-97 looks to me like it's about excluding *files* from analysis, whereas this question looks to me like it's about ignoring *rules*.

Comment: This seems to be no longer that case: When I uncheck a rule in settings (in the global settings dialog, not sonarlint's config dialog), it does not fire even though my server mandates it.