# How to suppress warning for a specific method with Intellij SonarLint plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, sonarlint, sonarlint-intellij

I want to suppress the Sonar lint plugin warning for some methods.
This question is not what I want [Intellij SonarLint 2.3 - ignore rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39449816/intellij-sonarlint-2-3-ignore-rule).

Currently I have to annotate the method with `@SuppressWarnings("all")`,which suppresses all warnings.

Comment: Well if you don't want to put the suppression in the code or in a rule on Sonar, where do you want it to go?

Comment: @dkanejs Intellij can suppress the warning using annotations  like `@SuppressWarnings("specific suppress id")`.

Comment: Ah I understand it is what you're asking now.

Comment: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Java+FAQ#JavaFAQ-SuppressWarnings ?

Comment: You only want to suppress warnings (related to Sonar lint) in a specific method ? You're looking for something to exist like `@SuppressWarnings("sonar")`

Answer (score 145, accepted):

You can use `//NOSONAR` or `@SuppressWarnings()` but you need to specify the rule.

From the SonarQube [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analyzing-source-code/languages/java/#turning-issues-off):

> The `//NOSONAR` tag is useful to deactivate all rules at a given line
> but is not suitable to deactivate all rules (or only a given rule) for
> all the lines of a method or a class. This is why support for
> `@SuppressWarnings("all")` has been added to SonarQube.
>
> SINCE 2.8 of Java Plugin, you can also use `@SuppressWarnings`
> annotation with a list of rule keys:
>
> `@SuppressWarnings("squid:S2078")`
>
> or
>
> `@SuppressWarnings({"squid:S2078", "squid:S2076"})`.

Comment: One thing to note is that IntelliJ will generate @SuppressWarnings("ALL") which SonarLint will ignore - it has to be "all".

Comment: How to add comments/justification while suppressing the warning?

Comment: Am I correct to assume there's no such capability for Python as of 2022-12-24? https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analyzing-source-code/languages/python/

Answer (score 1):

This annotation for scala method helped me

```scala
object Solution {
    @SuppressWarnings(Array("scala:S3776"))
    def threeSum(nums: Array[Int]): List[List[Int]] = {
        val sortedNums = nums.sorted
```

Answer (score -1):

You can Suppress an inspection in the editor it-self,

[image]

Refer to https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html, It has various methods to get this done, there are many ways to customize the required behaviors.

Comment: That submenu doesn't exist on SonarLint warnings (IDEA 2020.3.3, SonarLint 4.14.2.28348).

Comment: or maybe exists for Java files but not for Kotlin files