# Sonarlint warns me against a possible NullPointerException, but in my mind, I did what was necessary to prevent it?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, nullpointerexception, sonarlint

I've wrote this code that is working properly, but *Sonarlint* warns me against a `wsr.getBody().getWorkspace()` that could lead to a `NullPointerException` on `wsr.getBody()`, who could yield null, it says.

```java
public WorkspaceSummary getWorkspace(String workspaceName) {
   try {
      ResponseEntity<GetWorkspaceResponse> wsr = this.workspacesApi.getWorkspaceWithHttpInfo(workspaceName, this.quiet);

      if (wsr == null || wsr.getBody() == null) {
         throw new RuntimeException("getWorkspaceWithHttpInfo a renvoyé une réponse nulle");
      }

      return wsr.getBody().getWorkspace();
   }
   catch(HttpClientErrorException e) {
      [...]
   }
}
```

[image]

But I believe not. In my mind, I did what was necessary to prevent it.

Sometimes obvious things that are in front of us we don't see them, this is why I am asking you if I missed something.

Comment: dont know if this will even change anything, but do you want to try assigning wsr.getBody() to a variable, then using it in the checks and returning the variable.getWorkspace()?

Comment: One thing is that SonarQube is stupid. It will happily report false positives that even an average programmer sees are untrue. Suppress the warning unless you want to "code dance" to make SQ happy.

Comment: @Kayaman I've installed _Sonarlint_ in order to find troubles in my code. I won't desactivate its warnings.

Comment: I'd use the advice from @experimentunit1998X to assign it to a variable. Sonar probably can't infer that `wsr.getBody()` will always return the same result.

Comment: @Kayaman you can suppress a warning of a kind on a single line, but allow it to appear elsewhere on other sources you have? I know only how to disable a warning of sme kind entierely. In my mind, if I suppress the warning "_NullPointerException could be thrown_", _Sonarlint_ won't attempt to do that detection elsewhere in my sources.

Comment: [Of course](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47369526/2541560). It would be pretty useless if you couldn't suppress single warnings.

Comment: Thanks! It can be a solution, if everything else fails.

Comment: @experimentunit1998X I experienced it: it works and I've wrote it for a workaround answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assume that war.getBody() is consistent and always returns the same value.
Sonar looks at the code and sees that you are recalculating or refetching the value, so basically you didn’t validate the new value, so the value can be null.
If you save the value than there is no threat that the value will change.

Comment: That's clever! Yes, it's really understandable and wise. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer @oferskulsky gave can be applied the way @experimentunit1998X suggested, and it solves the warning. Great!

```java
ResponseEntity<GetWorkspaceResponse> wsr = this.workspacesApi.getWorkspaceWithHttpInfo(workspaceName, this.quiet);
GetWorkspaceResponse response = (wsr != null) ? wsr.getBody() : null;

if (response == null) {
   throw new RuntimeException("getWorkspaceWithHttpInfo a renvoyé une réponse nulle");
}

return response.getWorkspace();
```